# How to .wrap() elements returned from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

UPDATE: The answer works with FILTER not FIND.... I'm not sure why.

This has got me stumped. I've searched everywhere, but I have not found this specific question, so I am posting it.

I've got an application where I fill out some forms, then submit via jquery ajax to a php file, then get the data back. When I get the data back I am trying to wrap each .contentarea class with another div, but I can't get it to work.

Here's what I've got

```
$(document).delegate('.moduleform', 'submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

formData = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "text",
url: "layouts/" + folder + "/make-layout.php",
data: formData
}).done(function(data) {

$(data).filter('.contentarea').each(function(){

var html = $(this).html();
$(html).wrap('<div class="contentarea_container" data-module="freeform"></div>');

});

$('#container').append(data);
$('#load').dialog('close');
$('#loadContent').empty();

});
});
```

When I console.log($(this)); it looks like an object in the console. When I console.log($(this).html()); it looks like HTML. But for some reason I cannot figure out how to wrap each .contentarea with another div.

I think it has something to do with converting the data to HTML and back, or something like that. I'm able to target items in the data variable, but for some reason I just can't get the wrap to work. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.wrap` work on the DOM directly. So you append `data` to `#container` first, then call `.wrap` like this:

```
$(document).delegate('.moduleform', 'submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  formData = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "layouts/" + folder + "/make-layout.php",
    data: formData
  }).done(function(data) {
    var $data = $(data).appendTo('#container');
    $data.find('.contentarea').wrap('<div class="contentarea_container" data-module="freeform"></div>');
    $('#load').dialog('close');
    $('#loadContent').empty();
  });
});
```

Demo:

```js
var data = '<div><div class="contentarea">c</div></div><div><div class="contentarea">d</div></div>';
var $data = $(data).appendTo('#container');
$data.find('.contentarea').wrap('<div class="contentarea_container" data-module="freeform"></div>');
$('#out').text($('#container').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <div class="contentarea">a</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="contentarea">b</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: I thought about that, but the problem is that I have other .contentarea on the page that I don't want to be affected...

Comment: @garek007, I think you can use `appendTo` instead of `append` to get a reference to the elements you just added, then use `.find('.contentarea')` to operate on the elements you want

Comment: @garek007, I added a demo, it adds 2 new `.contentarea` and wrapped them without affecting the exisiting `.contentarea`. please check

Comment: That's exactly how I have it set up, except for the last line there. But you used regular HTML. Could it be that the data coming from the ajax call doesn't work like plain HTML? When I output to the console, it looks like an object.

Comment: the only difference is that I have an if else statement. Here is a link to the full file if it helps. https://jsfiddle.net/36Loyfc7/

Comment: @garek007, great. glad you figured it out